# Android activate and deactivate standby mode from the app

Tags: android

I have an app which runs in my company without user interaction. It is just a monitoring of current company processes. The devices are not portable, I am using android boxes with hdmi monitors. The devices are so configured that they never go in standby.  I want that the android box goes standby on a certain time and wake up on a certain time without user interaction. Is this possible from my code? Or is there an app that will do this for me?

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: Just a quick shot, you can use permisson.WAKE_LOCK and EDIT_SETTINGS and try it like described here. https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html  ----
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/13696891/programmatically-set-screen-to-off-in-android